# How do I get drivers for Windows 10 x64 installed on my Mac?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, driver, dual-boot

I've just installed windows 10 x64 on my mac, a partition that I made with Disk Utility. I was going to use BootCamp however the way BootCamp formatted the partition in El Capitan didn't allow Windows to be installed (I believe it was because of not formatting it correctly).

So now I've got it all installed however the drivers aren't (headphones and Wifi don't work; plus I'm not sure it's using my graphics card either).

How do I go about installing the drivers I need for this version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the partition and installation you made and go back to the BootCamp way. Then, inside the Windows installer, format the partition BootCamp makes for you, that is an extra step that is needed. Then, you can install Windows 10. I'd suggest using a USB stick to prepare the Windows 10 installation so that Drivers are included automatically.

If you do not want to follow this strategy, there is an option to download the BootCamp drivers separately, either from Apple's site, or from within the BootCamp utility on OSX, from one of the top menu's or the default assistant screen. The menu is called Action and has only one option: Download Windows Support Software. Once you have it downloaded, copy it over to a FAT32 USB stick so Windows can read it and your Mac can write it. exFAT might possibly work too. Reboot in to Windows and then open the bootcamp setup program form the directory you just downloaded and follow the on-screen steps.

Comment: I tried this in the first place - and the windows installer failed to format the drive.

Comment: Then use the second method where you download the support software manually, it should contain all the bootcamp stuff you need.

Comment: Ok sounds great - how do I know what drivers to get - for example where do I even start with NVIDIA? Sorry if I sound a little naive about this.

Comment: You need to download the bundle using the BootCamp Assistant. It contains all the drivers you need and one installation program to install everything at once. BootCamp Assistant -> Action menu -> Download